# Cocos2d play 2 different background music files or loop playEffect

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

I need to have to have a background music for the Scene and a background music for an Character,but I have to stop it when the character makes some actions.

For this problem I have to options:

1. Play 2 background music files in the same time, and stop the one related to the Character
2. Loop a sound effect.

Which one of this is 2 possible & recommended?

Regards!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You say you're using cocos2d so I've made the assumption that you're also using the `SimpleAudioEngine` provided with cocos2d.

With `SimpleAudioEngine`, it's not possible to play 2 background tracks. It is possible to loop effects with some small modifications:

- Provide a `-(int) playEffect:(NSString*) file loop:(BOOL) loop` message;
- In this method, you'll need to find out what play effect normally does. The thing you're looking out for is the `ALUInt` that is used as the handle for the sound. Keep a reference to this. You'll need it to stop the loop.
- Provide a `-(void) stopEffectWithHandle:(int) handle` that takes that in and passes it back to `OpenAL` to stop the effect.

**-EDIT-**

Here's some code for looping an effect:

```
int handle = [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:name];
if (loop) {
    alSourcei(handle, AL_LOOPING, 1);
}
return handle;
```

And some for stopping effects:

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] stopEffect:handle];
```

Comment: I found what effect is stoped on loop when you play a lot of another effects simultaneously.

Comment: I think this is because there is a limit in CocosDension of how many sounds can be simultaneously loaded.

Comment: After playing and stopping the sound nearly 32 times, it stops working. After some googling I found the memory pool is filled. I need to somehow release the sound object. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

@ToughGuy comment on @JamesWebster answer is right, I ran into the same problem with that solution.

I solved this problem using this approach from [this forum post](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1025#p45409).

Play effect with:

```
CDSoundSource *loopSound = [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] soundSourceForFile:LOOPING_SOUND_FILENAME];
loopSound.looping = YES;
[loopSound play];
```

And stop it with:

```
[loopSound stop];
```

Hope this helps.